# Firebase concurrency issue: how to prevent 2 users from getting the same Game Key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**DATABASE:**

[image]

---

**SITUATION:**

My website sells keys for a game.

A key is a randomly generated string of 20 characters whose uniqueness is guaranteed (not created by me).

When someone buys a key, `NTWKeysLeft` is read to find it's first element. That element is then copied, deleted from `NTWKeysLeft` and pasted to `NTWUsedKeys`.

Said key is then displayed on the buyer's screen.

---

**PROBLEM:**

How can I prevent the following problem :

1) 2 users buy the game at the exact same time.

2) They both get the same key read from `NTWKeysLeft` (first element in list)

3) And thus both get the same key

I know about Firebase Transactions already. I am looking for a pseudo-code/code answer that will point me in the right direction.

---

**CURRENT CODE:**

Would something like this work ? Can I put a transaction inside another transaction ?

```
var keyRef = admin.database().ref("NTWKeysLeft");
                keyRef.limitToFirst(1).transaction(function (keySnapshot) {
                    keySnapshot.forEach(function(childKeySnapshot) {
                        // Key is read here:
                        var key = childKeySnapshot.val();
                        // How can I prevent two concurrent read requests from reading the same key ? Using a transaction to change a boolean could only happen after the read happens since I first need to read in order to know which key boolean to change.
                        var selectedKeyRef = admin.database().ref("NTWKeysLeft/"+key);
                        var usedKeyRef = admin.database().ref("NTWUsedKeys/"+key);
                        var keysLeftRef = admin.database().ref("keysLeft");
                        selectedKeyRef.remove();
                        usedKeyRef.set(true);
                        keysLeftRef.transaction(function (keysLeft) {  
                            if (!keysLeft) { 
                                keysLeft = 0; 
                            } 
                            keysLeft = keysLeft - 1;
                            return keysLeft; 
                        });
                        res.render("bought", {key:key});
                    });
                });
```

Just to be clear:  `keyRef.limitToFirst(1).transaction(function (keySnapshot) {` does not work, but I would like to accomplish something to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

Most depends on how you generate the keys, since that determines how likely collisions are. I recommend reading about [Firebase's push IDs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) to get an idea how unique those are and compare that to your keys. If you can't statistically guarantee uniqueness of your keys or if statistical uniqueness isn't good enough, you'll have to [use transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to prevent conflicting updates.

Comment: The keys are unique. I just dont' want 2 users who paid at the same time to get the same key read from the database (as in 2 concurrent firebase reads of the first element for both users before said element is removed because it has been read and therefore becomes a used key to prevent other users from getting a used key)

Comment: Firebase has implemented  a solution for things like upvotes or counter using Firebase transactions. But I am unable to see what would be the solution to prevent concurrent reads of the same value in the Firebase Database. A value (a key) must be read once by one user and then deleted.

Comment: You could take a new key at random, instead of always the first one.

Comment: @TheProgrammer In that case transactions are your solution.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How ?

Comment: @BenWest That is sadly not doable :/ I would have to download the list as far as the potential highest random choice if I wanted to do that.

Comment: Question updated with my current code which does not prevent concurrent reads.

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to do solve this issue ?

Comment: Your current code doesn't use transactions, so has the problem that multiple users can make conflicting changes. Using transactions prevents that problem. Since transactions compare-and-set on a single location, you have to run them on the lowest level node that contains all data you're modifying. In your current data structure that is the root of all `NTWKeysLeft` and `NTWUsedKeys`, which may be more data that you'd like to read-and-modify. If so, consider a different data structure where the modification is more local, e.g. a single list of keys where the boolean indicates if it's been used.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I use a single list of keys, how can I select one with a transaction since  I don't know which one will be selected in advance ? It's apparently not possible to do something like `keyRef.limitToFirst(1).transaction(function (keySnapshot) {`

Answer (score 1):

The OP has changed the question a bit so, i will update the answer as follows: I will leave the bottom part about transactions as it was and will put the new update on top.

I can see two ways to proceed:

1) handle the lock system on your own and use JavaScript callbacks or other mechanisms for preventing simultaneous access to a portion of the code.

or

2) Use transactions/fireBase. On this case, i don't have the setup ready to share code other than sample/pseudo code provided at the bottom of this page.

With respect to option **1 above**:
I have coded a use-case and put in on plunker. It uses JavaScript callbacks to queue users as they try to access the part of the code under lock.

```
I. user comes in and he is placed in queue
II. It then calls the callback function which pops users as
first come first out bases. I have the keys on top of the page to
be shared by the functions.
```

I have a button click event to this and when you click the button twice quickly, you will see keys assigned and they're different keys.
To read this code, click on the script.js file on the left and read starting from the bottom of the page where it calls the functions.

Here is the sample code in plunker. After clicking it, click on Run on top of the page and then click on the button on right hand side. Alert will pop up to show which key is given (note, there are two calls back to back to show two users coming in at same time)

https://plnkr.co/edit/GVFfvqQrlLeMaKlo5FCj?p=info

***The fireBase transactions:***

Use fireBase transactions to prevent concurrent read/write issues - below is the transaction() method signiture

`transaction(dataToBeWritten, onComplete, applyLocally) returns fireBase.promise containing {
    committed: boolean, nullable fireBase.database.snapshot }`

Note, transaction needs writeOperation as first parameter and in your case looks like you’re removing a key upon success! hence the following function to be called in place of write

Try this pseudo code :

```
    //first, get reference to your db
    var selectedKeyRef = admin.database().ref("NTWKeysLeft/"+key);

   // needed by transaction as first parameter
  function writeOperation() {
     selectedKeyRef.remove();
  }

  selectedKeyRef.transaction(function(writeOperation) , function(error,   
  committed, snapshot) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
  } else if (!committed) {
    console.log('We aborted the transaction (because xyz).’);
  } else {
    console.log(‘keyRemoved!’);
  }
  console.log(“showKey: ", snapshot.val());
});  // end of the transaction() method call
```

Docs + to see  parameters/return objects of the transaction() method see:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction

In the Docs.... If another client writes to the location before your new value is successfully written, your update function is called again with the new current value, and the write is retried.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: I am not using Cloud Firestore, I am using the Realtime Database. I understand transactions are the answer, I am asking HOW I should use them in this case to solve my issue.

Comment: Added comments to code: // Key is read here: var key = childKeySnapshot.val(); // How can I prevent two concurrent read requests from reading the same key ? Using a transaction to change a boolean could only happen after the read happens since I first need to read in order to know which key boolean to change.

Comment: I thought about this, but it's very impractical and expensive.

Comment: This is missing the point: by the time I have `key` in `var selectedKeyRef = admin.database().ref("NTWKeysLeft/"+key);`,  the value has already been read, which means 2 users might already have read it.

Comment: I have explained that in the answer, read it carefully starting at “note”. Plus, this is pseudo code and you have to adapt it to your needs

Comment: Transaction () protects write operation which in your case is the remove the key operation.  If that doesn’t suit your need, you can revisit the setInterval() option

Comment: I have read your answer twice, where do you explain how you get the `key` value ? That is the whole point of my question, I already know how to use a transaction to prevent concurrent writes, I am asking about concurrent reads since I cannot apparently do something like `keyRef.limitToFirst(1).transaction(function (keySnapshot) {`

Comment: "Transaction () protects write operation which in your case is the remove the key operation. If that doesn’t suit your need, you can revisit the setInterval() option" I already explained why the setInterval() is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem you're worried about can happen. JavaScript, including Node, is single-threaded and can only do one thing at a time. If you had a big server infrastructure with more than one  server running this code, then it would be possible, but for a single Node program, there's no problem.

Comment: I will most likely end up having multiple instances running at the same time.

Comment: You could give each server its own list of keys so they don't have to share.

Comment: I have no way to do that :/ It's an autoscaled infrastructure managed by a third-party.

Comment: In that case I don't know, but I've got a feeling it's a really hard problem which causes a lot of sweat even for big developers. Maybe you could make this keys service separate from the rest of your program and only run it on one instance.

Comment: Question updated with my current code which does not prevent concurrent reads.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the previous answers discussing the scope of Transactions worked out, I would suggest a different workaround.

Is it possible to trigger the unique code generation when someone buys a code? If yes, you could generate the unique string if the "buy" button is clicked, display the ID and save the ID to your database.

Later the user enters the key in your game, which checks if the ID is written in your database. This might probably also save a bit of data, since you do not need to keep track of the unique IDs before they get bought and you will also not run out of IDs, since they will always get generated when necessary.

Comment: There is no unique code generation. The keys are not created by me.